# chromPlot R package: remove scales

Tags: snp, chromplot

I am using chromPlot R package to plot some SNPs and their associated score, however, I cannot find a way to remove the scale of such score (circled in the attached picture). Does anybody know how to do it?

Thank you so much.

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the code you use to generate the image.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `legChrom` argument to `NA` will omit plotting a legend.

Found in [the manual](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/chromPlot/inst/doc/chromPlot.pdf) for chromPlot on Bioconductor for release 3.7.